# Blender objects select

Tags: objects, edit-mode, select

The image attached, when I try to select part of the stadium, the whole stadium is selected, how can I separate this into different parts so I can edit different parts.

[image: sekect]
Thanks

Comment: When making titles to your questions please make them specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic, e.g. "How can I separate an object into different parts?"

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to make one object seperated into different objects, you can go to edit mode then selecting the parts that you want to seperate (if they are not connected to other parts pressing L speed up your selection or pressing ctrl and numpad's + or -, also selecting one point and then pressing shift and ctrl then selecting the opposite side of that could select the whole area, try it on a subdivided square to get how it works). After selecting the parts press P and click on seperate by selection. it will seperate the selection to a new object. hope it helps.